# Is it ok to use a Backbone model's cid as an html id attribute? Is it guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, model

I have a Backbone view that displays info from several different collections. Is it ok to use   those models' cid as html id attributes? In other words, are cid guaranteed to be unique across all models in all collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation says](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid):

> **cid** `model.cid`
>
> A special property of models, the **cid** or client id is a unique identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first created. Client ids are handy when the model has not yet been saved to the server, and does not yet have its eventual true **id**, but already needs to be visible in the UI.

There's no mention of collections or model types so they should be safe enough. There's no guarantee that a given `cid` won't be reused if say a model is destroyed but that might not matter to you and the only sensible implementation for `cid`s is to have a single global counter of some sort that gets incremented when a new `cid` is needed.

OTOH, if I had real model `id`s available, I'd use those instead.

Comment: It seems like using real model ids as html id attributes is probably not advisable on a page that is displaying models from more than one database table since there could be a collision. You have given me some confidence in using the cid for my implementation, although what I should probably do is break down my view structure a bit more so I don't have to search my collections for the right model based on DOM attributes.

Comment: You could combine the model `id` with the the model name to get an `id` attribute. Or just use `data-id="model_id" data-type="Model_name"` attributes instead and localize any selectors to the view in question.

Comment: Yes, I like the data attribute solution. That's a nice clean way to get fully qualified references.